# Permission problem jenkins (HTTPError: 500 Server Error)

Tags: server, jenkins-pipeline

```
`FAILED! => {
"changed": false,
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "config": "<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n<hudson>\n  <disabledAdministrativeMonitors/>\n  <version>2.387.2</version>\n  <numExecutors>2</numExecutors>\n  <mode>NORMAL</mode>\n  <useSecurity>true</useSecurity>\n  <authorizationStrategy class=\"hudson.security.FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy\">\n    <denyAnonymousReadAccess>true</denyAnonymousReadAccess>\n  </authorizationStrategy>\n  <securityRealm class=\"hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm\">\n    <disableSignup>true</disableSignup>\n    <enableCaptcha>false</enableCaptcha>\n  </securityRealm>\n  <disableRememberMe>false</disableRememberMe>\n  <projectNamingStrategy class=\"jenkins.model.ProjectNamingStrategy$DefaultProjectNamingStrategy\"/>\n  <workspaceDir>${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}</workspaceDir>\n  <buildsDir>${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds</buildsDir>\n  <jdks/>\n  <viewsTabBar class=\"hudson.views.DefaultViewsTabBar\"/>\n  <myViewsTabBar class=\"hudson.views.DefaultMyViewsTabBar\"/>\n  <clouds/>\n  <scmCheckoutRetryCount>0</scmCheckoutRetryCount>\n  <views>\n    <hudson.model.AllView>\n      <owner class=\"hudson\" reference=\"../../..\"/>\n      <name>all</name>\n      <filterExecutors>false</filterExecutors>\n      <filterQueue>false</filterQueue>\n      <properties class=\"hudson.model.View$PropertyList\"/>\n    </hudson.model.AllView>\n  </views>\n  <primaryView>all</primaryView>\n  <slaveAgentPort>-1</slaveAgentPort>\n  <label></label>\n  <crumbIssuer class=\"hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer\">\n    <excludeClientIPFromCrumb>false</excludeClientIPFromCrumb>\n  </crumbIssuer>\n  <nodeProperties/>\n  <globalNodeProperties/>\n  <nodeRenameMigrationNeeded>false</nodeRenameMigrationNeeded>\n</hudson>",
        "enabled": null,
        "name": "paper build Pipeline (Ansible)",
        "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
        "state": "present",
        "token": null,
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
        "user": "HladRom",
        "validate_certs": true
    }
},
"msg": "Unable to create job, Error in request. Possibly authentication failed [500]: Server    `
```

This is a playbook that installs jenkins on another machine and configures it.
At the stage"Create a jenkins job using basic authentication" I get a problem. It seems to me with access.
what can I do?